# Get items from SharePoint 2013 list where permission inheritance is broken

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

I am trying to select all the items from a list that has unique permissions. When I load the list, ItemCount == 1 but after I load the items for the list, the ListItemCollection count == 0.The app has full control to the site collection, web and list.

```
        var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);
        using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(spContext.SPHostUrl))
        {
            clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web.Lists,
                    lists => lists.Include(list => list.Title,
                                    list => list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl,
                                    list => list.Id,
                                    list => list.Hidden,
                                    list => list.BaseTemplate,
                                    list => list.BaseType,
                                    list => list.EffectiveBasePermissions,
                                    list => list.ItemCount,
                                    list => list.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
                    .Where(list => list.BaseType == BaseType.DocumentLibrary && 
                        list.HasUniqueRoleAssignments == true && 
                        list.Title == "Test Library"));

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            //clientContext.Web.Lists.FirstOrDefault().ItemCount == 1
            var tempItems = clientContext.Web.Lists.FirstOrDefault().GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100));
            clientContext.Load(tempItems);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            //tempItems.Count() == 0
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem, it was a permission issue.